# Null output from Runtime.getRuntime.exec() in java

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I am trying to execute a series of JDEPS commands using a loop in java. I have used Process object to capture the execution of the command([`Runtime.getRuntime.exec("command")`][1]), and using [`BufferedReader`][2] to take the process input and error streams. But the output is coming as null. There are no error codes as well. I have run the command manually on the terminal and it work fine.

Can anybody suggest anyway of how to figure out what is the issue, or as to why this null output is coming?

Please find my code for executing the command below:

```
private String[] runCommandByType(String command,int type)
{
    String s=null;
    ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {

        // using the Runtime exec method:
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

        // read the output from the command
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            if(type==0) //takes in all the output
            {
                output.add(s);
            }
            if(type==1) //takes only the dependent class names
            {
                s=s.substring(0, s.indexOf("->")).replaceAll("\\s+","");
                output.add(s);
            }
        }
        // read any errors from the attempted command
        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("$$$$ Exception happened $$$$");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return output.toArray(new String[output.size()]);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you share some part of your code.

Comment: @DenisIsmailovski please find the code in the post. I have added it.

Comment: Give us your command.

Comment: the command is somewhat like this: jdeps -v <classpath>

Comment: Your code works for me, your problem is in the command I think.

Comment: the command is not the problem, because it works fine when i try it on the terminal. The problem with this is that, the output is coming null when I am executing through java. There is nothing on the ErrorSteam as well. I can't figure out what is going on during the execution.

Comment: When I issue a single command, it works fine. But when I put it in a loop and I am calling this method multiple times and executing multiple commands. Then it is coming as null.

Comment: What OS is running your code? if you're using windows, then the command should be: String[] command = {"cmd" , "/c" , "jdeps" , "-v" , "..."} on linux it should be like String[] command = {"sh" , "-c" , "jdeps" , "-v" , "..."} (or bash instead of sh)

Comment: Do you call this method in a different thread?

Comment: @MartínZaragoza I am running this on Linux. i am using the command like this:
String command="jdeps -v "+classpath;
Then executing this in that method. It worked for one command, but it shows null when I am putting it in loops and when I try to execute multiple commands.

Comment: @MBaev, no not using a different thread. Should I try to do that?

Comment: Work fine for me. [See it](https://ibb.co/fLE89T)

Comment: Yes, I know. It works fine for me too when I am issuing a single command. Can you try to call this method multiple times and execute it multiple times, and check if it's working out for you?

Comment: This class command is not working when I am trying to execute using the java.

Comment: If you call it many times you should destroy the process I think?

Comment: I thought so, tried it out. But anyway, figured out that the problem was with the command. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: 1) See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).